# Стандартный шаблонизатор Go. Как вставить шаблон в другой шаблон?

Tags: golang, golang-gin

Суть вот в чем.
к примеру у меня есть несколько шаблонов

base.tmpl

```
<div id="content">
{{ ВСТАВИТЬ СЮДА КОНТЕНТ }}
</div>
```

index.tmpl

```
{{ вставиться в base.tmpl }}
<h4 id="last-with-photo">Последние объявления с фото</h4>
```

в общем хендлер подгружает index.tmpl и нужно чтобы он входил в base.tmpl в нужное место (куда-то в центр)
как бы это сделать, чтобы не разбивать base.tmpl на части?

Answer (score 1):

## Block template из go1.6

*default.html*

```
<html>
<head>
    {{block "head" .}} {{end}}
</head>
<body>
{{block "body" .}} {{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

*about.html*

```
{{define "head"}}
<title>About</title>
{{end}}
{{define "body"}}
Hello!!
{{end}}
```

Таким образом можно очень удобно группировать различные блоки для разных шаблонов. Проверь описание блоков в text/template

## Gin

У меня нет репутации для ссылок проверь баг 567 в репозитории gin на гитхабе.

Джин завязан, что нельзя использовать несколько шаблонов одновременно. Проблема обсуждается в 567. Но существует интерфейс multitemplate  в репозитории gin-contrib .

## Реальный пример

Я реализовал много шаблонов в репозитории **im7mortal/gowall**. В папке *layouts* содержаться основные шаблоны. В папке *views* динамические блоки. В файле *cmd/gowall/templates.go* я встраиваю блоки в шаблоны в *multitemplate.Render*.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать можно по-разному. Я обычно на своих проектах пользуюсь таким хелпером:

```
var (
    errNoLayout   = errors.New("no layout")
    errNoTemplate = errors.New("no template")
)

func executeTemplate(tmpls *template.Template, tmplName string, w io.Writer, data interface{}) error {
    var err error
    layout := tmpls.Lookup("layout.html")
    if layout == nil {
        return errNoLayout
    }

    layout, err = layout.Clone()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    t := tmpls.Lookup(tmplName)
    if t == nil {
        return errNoTemplate
    }

    _, err = layout.AddParseTree("content", t.Tree)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return layout.Execute(w, data)
}
```

Здесь `tmpls` - это шаблон, в котором загружены все файлы, такой шаблон можно получить например если вызвать [`ParseGlob`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseGlob). layout.html - базовый шаблон вида

```
<!-- html, body, etc. -->
<main class="container">
  {{template "content" .}}
</main>
```

Остальные шаблоны подгружаются по имени `tmplName`. Пример вызова:

```
err = executeTemplate(h.tmpl, "place_index.html", w, data)
if err != nil {
    h.logger.Printf("can't execute template: %v", err)
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
```

Answer (score -1):

пример реализации рендеринга с автоперегрузкой шаблонов с собственными фильтрами. https://github.com/spouk/spoukfw/blob/master/spoukrender.go   Кури.

По шаблонам.
Пример:
Создаешь 3 файла **head.html**

```
{{define "head"}} 
<!--variables-->
{{ $path := call .stack.session.Fn.path }}
{{ $param := .stack.session.Fn.param}}
{{ $query := .stack.session.Fn.query }}
{{ $flash := .stack.session.Fn.result }}
{{ $command := call $param "command" }}
{{ $id := call $param "id" }}
{{ $user := .user.user }}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!--seo block-->
    <title>{{if .seo.Title}} {{.seo.Title}} {{end}}</title>
    <meta name="Description" content="{{if .seo.Desc }} {{.seo.Desc}} {{end}}">
    <meta name="Keywords" content="{{if .seo.Keys }} {{.seo.Keys}} {{end}}">
    <meta name="robots" content="{{if .seo.robots}} {{.seo.robots}} {{end}}">
    <!--end seo block-->

    <!-- icons set fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/fonts/flaticon_set/flaticon.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <script src="/static/js/respond/respond.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <!--adding icons styles-->
    <link href="/static/icons/interact/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/icons/ultimate/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--main js libs-->
    <script src="/static/js/spoukjs/spouk_sitesupport.js"></script>


    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/uikit.min.css" />-->
    {{ if .stack.csrf }}{{ html2 (call .stack.csrf.Csrf_head) }}{{end}}
</head>

{{end}}
```

Это базовый шаблон для "шапки" остальных шаблонов. 
Средняя часть **index.html**

```
{{template "head" .}} <-- вставляем содержимое head.html сюда этой конструкцией

<!--variables-->
{{ $request := .stack.request }}
{{ $path := call .stack.session.Fn.path }}
{{ $param := .stack.session.Fn.param}}
{{ $query := .stack.session.Fn.query }}
{{ $flash := .stack.session.Fn.result }}
{{ $command := call $param "command" }}
{{ $id := call $param "id" }}
{{ $user := .user.user }}

{{ $cont := .stack.cont }}
{{ $bread := call .stack.bread $cont}}

тут средняя часть 

сюда вставляю footer 

{{template "footer" .}}
```

**footer.html**

```
{{define "footer"}}


<div class="col-xs-12 footer_style spouk_container">
    <div class="blog_footer">

 ....

{{end}}
```

И вкури мануал по шаблонам, он простой.