# golang template define срабатывает один и тот же шаблон

Tags: golang, шаблоны

Создал файл app.html - как layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Control Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/prod/css/app.css">
    <script src="/prod/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    {{template "content" .}} // сюда будет подставляться define из других файлов,
                                но подставляется только из index.html,
                                когда должно подставляться из add.html,
                                то все равно подставляется из index.html

</body>
</html>
```

Далее создаю index.html для вывода как основная страница роута "/":

```
{{template "app.html" .}}

{{define "content}}
    Контент index.html
{{end}}
```

Далее создал add.html для вывода роута "/add":

```
{{template "app.html" .}}

{{define "content}}
    Контент add.html
{{end}}
```

Но когда захожу на "/add" то выводится содержимое "content" из index.html, то есть содержимое define из add.html не срабатывает (видимо перезаписывается из index.html)
Как распределять, что бы срабатывало?

Comment: Предполагаю, что вы неправильно парсите шаблоны. Без кода сказать сложно. Посмотрите, например, этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624651/180092.

Comment: @Ainar-G использую gin framework router.LoadHTMLGlob("tmpl/*") - то есть парсятся все файлы сразу

Comment: вообщем уже не актуально, нашел ответ тут https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/320#issuecomment-109643671

Comment: Можете написать ответ на свой же вопрос, чтобы люди с подобной проблемой быстрее получили решение.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать директиву **block** чем **template**.

[Я уже отвечал на этот вопрос. Как я понял ты используешь gin. В моем ответе есть подробное описание как в gin это реализовать.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624633/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-go-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD/643924#643924)